# Why do some r10k configuration files start their YAML lines with :?

Tags: puppet, yaml, r10k

I'm looking at setting up r10k for Puppet deployment, and I have various example r10k.yaml configuration files, but some seem to use an extra : at the start of many lines, for instance, at http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/r10k/1.1.4:

```
---
:cachedir: '/var/cache/r10k'
```

However, at https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/master/r10k.yaml.example:

```
---
cachedir: '/var/cache/r10k'
```

What's the difference, and why would I use one of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is how foreman do there variable

```
:cachedir: '/var/cache/r10k'
```

will be read as

```
{
  ":cachedir": "/var/cache/r10k"
}
```

You can test your syntax here :
http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

foreman var : http://www.theforeman.org/manuals/1.5/index.html#3.5.2ConfigurationOptions

Comment: can you give an example of it's use with multiple keys for completeness please ?

Comment: i edited my answer

Comment: This prepending of : to YAML lines seems to happen almost everywhere in the Puppet/Foreman world. Is the one without the error?

Comment: it does :varname, they did like that by convention (i added a link)